Databricks SQL Query for finding rows having special characters and discard those rows
As part of Databricks, We would like to filter rows having special characters in the columns.
Let's say we have a Table with data like:
Table1 has
Col1

199 Central Avenue
1664 O'block Road
1630 Hahn's Dairy Road
"N 40 Degrees 36' 15"" W -75 Degrees -27' -52"""
4061605 North Lat-7538'39* West Long.
"40ï¿½3'13"" North

Except the Last row, all rows are valid here. How do we filter just the last row here
Tried out following:
select b.*
from Table1
where (Col1 REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9-&@.,/()#''``:$"" ]')
This is still showing all rows except 1st row.
Tried out following:
select b.*
from Table1
where (Col1 REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9-&@.,/()#''``:$"" ]')
This is still showing all rows except 1st row.

199 Central Avenue
1664 O'block Road
577 Saint John's Road
1630 Hahn's Dairy Road                         --> Row 1
"N 40 Degrees 36' 15"" W -75 Degrees -27' -52"""
4061605 North Lat-7538'39* West Long.
"40ï¿½3'13"" North

Hi - what’s this comment meant to be? Why did you add it?

You can use below query where you need to add you special characters that you want
to avoid.
SELECT  *  FROM Table1 WHERE (Col1 not REGEXP '[+ï¿½]')

Here, i am adding whatever the characters i don't want which presents one or more times  in the record .
+: For having characters one or more time.
ï¿½: Special characters i don't want.
Output:


@Nanda Check if above provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?
